# Selenium Webdriver - driver.get() not working correctly when inserting a variable inside

Tags: selenium, webdriver

**This is solved. I had my baseURL wrong. And it was going to a different site, that redirected to the base url of the correct site. Thanks.**

I have a problem using driver.get() with a variable inside. For example:

```
driver.get(baseURL+othervariable);
```

When I execute it, the browser goes to baseURL alone.

I have added before that line a console print to make sure the concatenation is ok, like:

```
System.out.println(baseURL+othervariable);
driver.get(baseURL+othervariable);
```

And I can see in the console that the concatenation is ok.

The weird thing is that if I insert the url directly without base url, like:

```
driver.get("http://examplesite.com/subsection");
```

It works.

Why am I facing this problem? because I'm using a for cycle in order to open an array of URLs that I need to check.

So the structure of my program is something like:

```
for (i=0 ; i<URLs.lenght ; i++) {
driver.get(baseURL + URLs[i]);
// then do some stuff
}
```

But the browser always open baseURL alone.

The weird thing is that I don't have any problem when executing this in the lower environments of this website. The problem occurs with the Live site.

Could it be that some configuration in the site is preventing Selenium from going to the desired URL?

But then I don't understand why when I insert the URL directly as a String into driver.get(), it works as expected, even in the live site.

So the problem is when I insert a variable inside, and only in the live site.

I'm totally confused. I tried Firefox driver, Chrome driver, etc. All do the same.

I also tried:

```
String finalURL = baseURL+URLs[i];
driver.get(finalURL);
```

And it refuses to open the complete URL. I never had this problem in many tests. Many times I executed driver.get() with variables and concatenations inside and I never faced this problem.

Could someone give me a hint? why is the problem only appearing when sending the URL as a variable but not when I send it as a String?

I'm using Selenium 3.0 btw.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try by writing implicit wait/ explicit wait?

Comment: in this case my intention is to write navigate().to() is useful instead of get(). if still issue reproducing then you can add implicit wait before calling the url

Comment: Did U tried to print finalUrl before you put it into adres ??? How it looks like???

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could solve the issue. The baseURL was wrong. It was going to, for example. www.a.com instead of www.b.com

a.com had a redirection rule to b.com, so when I entered a.com/subsection it always redirected to b.com homepage.

I didn't realize I was trying to access an old url. The domain name changed. That was my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to be sure of URLs syntaxe (especially \ and //)
For some website, incorrect URLs redirect to baseURL page.
If you're working on an AngularJS project, you may need some waits (try ngWebDriver)
Good luck !

Comment: Man, after two days of struggling with it, it turned out that I had the baseURL variable incorrectly spelled, and actually going to another website. But that "other website" had a redirection rule and redirected me to the base url of the correct website. The problem was not with / or \, the problem was even more simple.

Comment: Problem solved : we all struggle with this man, we search for the difficult answer, anyway ! Good luck ! :)